# Is it possible to disable/increase HTML node text-limit (10,000) in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]I've got a HTML page with a node that contains a bunch of text. (more than 10,000 characters)

```
<html>Lorem ipsum ...</html>
```

Inside the DOM tree of the Chrome Developer Tools, the node's text is truncated after 10,000 characters, showing only "…" at the end.
If you double click the text in the dev tools and click back into your document, it gets truncated as well.

Is there a switch/config for disabling this behaviour? Or at least a possibility to increase this limit?

- Chrome Version: 26.0.1410.65
- Tested Operating Systems: OSX 10.8.3, Windows 7 SP1 x64
- Installed Extensions: Google Docs (on Mac), None (on Windows)

The node-text in the screenshot consists of 10,000 Lorem ipsum character followed by sequences of "A"s.

Comment: Just tested it on version '26.0.1410.65' on Mac with 267621 characters and got everything displayed in the DevTools. Can you be more specific on your platform/Chrome version?

Comment: Same Chrome version here...
I added Platform specifics, screenshot, and modified scenario description. (No tab-switch, just double click inside dev-tools and back in the main window)

Comment: Sounds to me like a Chrome bug, rather than a feature that one could disable/change.